# Dota2 packet analysis uknown wiretype for proto message

Tags: networking, protocol-buffers

I am trying to gain access to in game chat information from dota2 packets. I knew this used to possible since there were multiple projects that intercepted dota2 network traffic and translated chat text to print out on an overlay over dota2. Right now I am using wireshark with protobuf addon installed. I can see a few packets here and there to valve servers outside the USA and can see the protobuf addon for wireshark working on these packets but I get an unknown wiretype error for 95% of the packets I believe to be related to dota. In almost all of these packets the UDP data payload starts off with 56 53 30 31
here is an example hex dump from wireshark. Are these 4 bytes some sort of header and then the proto messages start?

```
0000   c8 a7 0a a4 63 ed 6c fd b9 4b 6e 16 08 00 45 00

0010   00 70 58 db 40 00 40 11 85 1a c0 a8 01 f5 d0 40

0020   c9 a9 9e 96 69 89 00 5c 72 7c **56 53 30 31** 30 00

0030   06 00 00 02 00 00 00 1d fe 11 11 10 00 00 d7 0a

0040   00 00 01 00 00 00 11 10 00 00 30 00 00 00 24 fd

0050   37 3c b4 30 a5 48 fa 3d ea 30 1a 1f d8 a9 41 e0

0060   e0 6c 44 ba bb 4e ba fc e7 ac ed f9 40 19 86 20

0070   84 71 52 5d b3 1f da 36 40 d9 b6 2e e1 e5
```

Comment: If you skip those bytes, 30 00 06 is *also* invalid protobuf. What makes you think this is protobuf data? If you want to try some sections, https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode accepts hex and will try to decode it. Don't include the line prefixes.

Comment: Im sure this packet is coming from dota2 and all the documentation I have read so far says they used protobufs. Some of the packets coming to the same ports are protobuf messages so it very well could  be invalid protobuf data. I have read that the replays for dota2 which are just packet dumps all start with an 12 byte header so i thought that maybe for live games the valid protobuf data would start after the header but I havent turned up a pattern that I see yet outside of those 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

That is ascii code for "VS01", so yes, it might be some kind of version identifier.